# How do I force a SharePoint site to turn off compatibility mode and render in IE Edge without access to SharePoint Designer?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, internet-explorer-11

My SharePoint site pages are rendering in ie8 by default even though I am on IE11. I do not have access to sharePoint Designer so I can't edit the master page unfortunately. How do I force my site pages to show in IE Edge?

Answer (score 0):

goto http://sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx and download the masterpage,  edit in notepad/whatever then upload it again.  (alternativly open with explorer view,  and use Notepad++ or something that can open a URI location, make the change and save it.